# Installing glib gives "You must have either have gettext support"

Tags: glib, gettext

I'm trying to install `glib-2.37.6` (also same problem with `glib-2.32.1`) and getting this error during configuration:

> You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
>   GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html

I previously built `gettext`, though.  To clarify, I'm trying to build a number of things (leading up to `gtk+`) without actually installing in the usual places, since this is a machine others use; instead, I'm using `--prefix=` to put everything in a work directory under my home directory.

I tried looking at the logs to see if I could get a clue about whether I needed to set anything else.  I also tried looking at the `configure` script, although I'm not an expert on `autoconf`.  What I found was that the error occurred because `gt_cv_have_gettext` wasn't set to `yes`.  So then I looked for where it was supposed to get set, so that I could tell what file or whatever it was checking for.  But unless I'm missing something, the only command that would set it to `yes` is underneath this `if`:

```
  if test "$gt_cv_func_dgettext_libc" != "yes" \
     || test "$gt_cv_func_ngettext_libc" != "yes" \
     || test "$ac_cv_func_bind_textdomain_codeset" != "yes" ; then
```

The `config.log` (looking at the `configure` line numbers) indicates that the condition was false, so everything inside (including the command to set `gt_cv_have_gettext`) was skipped.  But the test seems to check that none of three things are missing.  And none of them are; here's one of the last segments of `config.log` right before the error:

```
configure:7982: checking for ngettext in libc
configure:8000: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
configure:8000: $? = 0
configure:8009: result: yes
configure:8013: checking for dgettext in libc
configure:8031: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
configure:8031: $? = 0
configure:8040: result: yes
configure:8047: checking for bind_textdomain_codeset
configure:8047: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
configure:8047: $? = 0
configure:8047: result: yes
configure:8323: checking for msgfmt
```

(The line that would set `gt_cv_have_gettext` is somewhere between 8047 and 8323.)  So unless I'm missing something, it looks as though if all these three things--`ngettext`, `dgettext`, `bind_textdomain_codeset`--are present (or succeed, or something), then an error will result.

So what am I missing?  Is there some other option that needs to be set, or something else wrong with my configuration?  Or did I find an error in the `configure` script?  Thanks for any help.  I wanted to ask in a forum like this before submitting it as a bug report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out.  Since I was "installing" everything in a directory under my `home` directory, I needed to add the `bin` subdirectory of the `--prefix` directory to my `$PATH` before running `configure`.  That made it find `msgfmt` and, I think, got it around the error.

Comment: Great question--thanks for posting it, and following up with the solution to help others! Ordinarily it is possible to specify a prefix whose `bin` directory isn't in `PATH` (or even without a pre-existing `bin` directory). But when building requires the use of tools that are actually installed in `$PREFIX/bin`, that directory does indeed need to be in `PATH`.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds very weird, normally when configuring the bin variable is set as `$PREFIX/bin` as said Eliah. Maybe I need to build glib again to test this. BTW, have you not used the jhbuild tool instead to do this? Also the pkgconfig path that so many headaches gave me in the past, wouldn't be interfering with your installation

Comment: @Braiam: If your question is intended for me, I don't know what `jhbuild` is.  I'm not an expert at GNU builds; I just try to follow the installation instructions.  Maybe it's something I'll have to read up on ...